# Flask API optional parameter is not working

Tags: api, rest, flask, routes, optional-parameters

I have a route that was created via flask_restplus.Api, not flask.Flask.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource

flask_app = Flask(__name__)
app = Api(app=flask_app)
name_space = app.namespace('', description="Описание маршрутизаций")
```

And I would like to send an optional parameter like this, [in the docs.](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#url-route-registrations) Here is my code to send optional parameter:

```
from flask_restplus import Resource

@name_space.route("/structure/", defaults={'path': None})
@name_space.route("/structure/<string:path>")
@name_space.doc(params={'path': {'description': 'Get structure of a given path'}})
class struct_level(Resource):
    def get(self, path):
        print(path) # shows None
        return method_to_work()
```

I've tried to change slashes in the end and to change method to post, nothing helped. Whatever value I send to 'path' parameter it returns None. If I make 'path' parameter required it works well, however I need this parameter to be optional, so that I can pass empty value.
Please, help me with an advice: how to make 'path' parameter optional in a route that was created by Api. Thanks!

P.S: Also, it is needed to be one endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I realised from my coworkers, that it is impossible to make this request in one route(endpoint). So I just had to create two endpoints, and that was ok.